# How to update the permissions of a person across all channels

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot but I'm stuck at the mute command, it should be like this: -mute @someone and leave him on mute until he gets unmuted, i got it to work on only the channel that the command was given in but it isn't what I wanted, help, please.

````
client.on('message',message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}mute`) && (muted[message.author]==0 || muted[message.author]==undefined))
    {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.channel.send("```You are not allowed to do this!```")
        }
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.channel.send("**I can't do this!**")
        }
        let target = message.mentions.members.first();
        if(target.id === message.author.id) {
            return message.reply("**You can't mute yourself**")
        }
        if(muted[target]==undefined)
        {
            muted[target]=0;
        }
        if(muted[target]==0)
        {
            muted[target]=1;
            let ch={};
            ch=message.guild.channels;   
            for (const cha in ch) 
            {
                let channe=ch[cha]; 
                channe.updateOverwrite(target, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: true
                  })  
            }
            message.channel.send(`${target} ** was muted.**`);
        }
        else
        {
            message.reply("**You can't mute this person again**")
        }
    }
})
````

Answer (score 0):

I have heavily modified your code and added a few extra checks, including making sure the message wasn't sent by a bot and checking if the mentioned used can be found.

I am also using [`Discord.Collection()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) instead of a normal JavaScript object, and improved the way commands are handled.

```js
let muted = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  switch (command) {
    case 'mute':
      if (!message.member.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**You are not allowed to mute members.**');
      if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**I am not allowed to mute members.**');

      const member = message.mentions.members.first();
      if (!member) return message.reply('**I could not find the mentioned user.**');
      if (member.id === message.author.id) return message.reply('**You cannot mute yourself.**');

      if (muted.has(member.id)) {
        message.reply('**You cannot mute this member again.**');
      } else {
        muted.set(member.id, true);

        message.guild.channels.cache.each(channel => {
          channel.updateOverwrite(member, { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false });
        });

        message.channel.send(`**${member.user.username} was muted.**`);
      }
      break;
    default:
      message.reply(`The command \`${command}\` was not recognized.`);
  }
});
```

I have also created a modified version with an additional `unmute` command:

```js
let muted = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  let member;

  switch (command) {
    case 'mute':
      if (!message.member.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**You are not allowed to mute members.**');
      if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**I am not allowed to mute members.**');

      member = message.mentions.members.first();
      if (!member) return message.reply('**I could not find the mentioned user.**');
      if (member.id === message.author.id) return message.reply('**You cannot mute yourself.**');

      if (muted.has(member.id)) {
        message.reply('**You cannot mute this member again.**');
      } else {
        muted.set(member.id, true);

        message.guild.channels.cache.each(channel => {
          channel.updateOverwrite(member, { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false });
        });

        message.channel.send(`**${member.user.username} was muted.**`);
      }
      break;
    case 'unmute':
      if (!message.member.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**You are not allowed to unmute members.**');
      if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('**I am not allowed to unmute members.**');

      member = message.mentions.members.first();
      if (!member) return message.reply('**I could not find the mentioned user.**');

      if (muted.has(member.id)) muted.delete(member.id);

      message.guild.channels.cache.each(channel => {
        channel.updateOverwrite(member, { 'SEND_MESSAGES': true });
      });

      message.channel.send(`**${member.user.username} was unmuted.**`);
      break;
    default:
      message.reply(`The command \`${command}\` was not recognized.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i didn't know anything about a discord collection and that helped a lot and I'm sure it will help me in the future too , thanks man.